# Multiple tables same column data structure CFC JSON

Tags: json, coldfusion, cfc

I am trying to get back a list of types from a cfc, and return it as a JSON.  The issue is how to create the structure of the JSON.  I have been racking my brain, trying to get this in a json format, and I'm not sure it is possible as currently written.

So here is the setup.  I have 4 tables, all but one column is identical.  I need multiple rows from each table.

I tried getting the appropriate data from each table like so:

```
<cfscript>
    tempStruct = setAttributionTypes(dsn,type);
    tempStruct = setCharacteristicTypes(dsn,type);
    //tempArray = setExposureTypes(dsn,type);
    //tempArray = setWeightTypes(dsn,type);             
</cfscript>
```

As you can see, I was trying to different methods.  Creating a struct, and creating an array of structs(not shown)

Here is the current query that I am using to bring all of the fields back in one column:

```
<cfquery name="getAllTypes" datasource="#dsn#">
    SELECT udc_code,
           type
    FROM(
        SELECT attribution_id AS udc_code,type
        FROM   tbl_asset_profile_template_attributions
        WHERE  template_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#type#">
        UNION ALL
        SELECT characteristic_id AS udc_code,type
        FROM   tbl_asset_profile_template_characteristics
        WHERE  template_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#type#">
        UNION ALL
        SELECT exposure_id AS udc_code,type
            FROM   tbl_asset_profile_template_exposures
        WHERE  template_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#type#">
        UNION ALL
        SELECT weight_id AS udc_code,type
        FROM   tbl_asset_profile_template_weights
        WHERE  template_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#type#">) AS tbl
    GROUP  BY type,
                 udc_code
    ORDER  BY type 
</cfquery>
```

I created a structure like `[{'attribution1':data,...}{...}]`, but that is pretty hard to process through.

I've been trying to create a structure like this:

```
 [{ATTRIBTUIONS{'TYPE1','TYPE2',}},{CHARACTERISTICS{'TYPE1',...}}]
```

I'm just having a hard time visualizing what I need.

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried simply `serializeJSON(getAllTypes, true)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of query tweaking and data massaging you can get the json object you want:

1) change your query to this:

```
<cfquery name="getAllTypes" datasource="#dsn#">
SELECT profilename,udc_code
FROM (
    SELECT attribution_id AS udc_code, type, 'Attributions' AS profilename
    FROM   tbl_asset_profile_template_attributions
    WHERE  template_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#type#">
    UNION ALL
    SELECT characteristic_id AS udc_code, type, 'Characteristics' AS profilename
    FROM   tbl_asset_profile_template_characteristics
    WHERE  template_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#type#">
    UNION ALL
    SELECT exposure_id AS udc_code, type, 'Exposures' AS profilename
    FROM   tbl_asset_profile_template_exposures
    WHERE  template_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#type#">
    UNION ALL
    SELECT weight_id AS udc_code, type, 'Weights' AS profilename
    FROM   tbl_asset_profile_template_weights
    WHERE  template_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#type#">) AS tbl
GROUP  BY profilename, type, udc_code
ORDER  BY profilename, type 
</cfquery>
```

2) create a struct to hold your data and populate it using cfoutput with GROUP attribute:

```
<cfset stTypes = structnew()>

<cfoutput query="getAllTypes" group="profilename">
 <cfset stTypes[getAllTypes.profilename] = arraynew(1)>
 <cfoutput>
  <cfset arrayappend(stTypes[getAllTypes.profilename], getAllTypes.type)>
 </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

3) serialize the struct into a json object:

```
<cfset jsonobj = serializejson(stTypes)>
```

This will create a json object like this:

```
{'Attributions':['Type1', 'Type2',...], 'Characteristics':['TypeA', 'TypeB',...], ...}
```

hth